# Mass re-rerun / re-evaluation of related records

Tags: trigger, batch, visual-workflow, update

I have an object called Journey. Each record of this object is made of several **Steps(object)** and **Sub-Steps(object)**.
To create a Journey record, I use a Template (Journey Template object).

When adding a Template to a Journey record, the ***steps and sub-steps*** for that record are automatically created via a trigger with the infos of these newly created records matching the ***Template Step & Template sub-Step*** infos

What I need is, anytime changes occur at Template level (***whether the update is made on the Journey Template, Template Step or Template sub-step object***).
These changes need to be mirrored at the Journey level.

*For example, if I remove a Template Step from the Journey Template (e.g Journey Template Name: **Marketing BNPP - Template**)*.
The same step needs to be removed on the Journey object that uses the same Journey Template.

[image]

What I tried to do, as a first part of my logic is to identify when a change occurs at template level and update the field "**Template Last Modified**".
So anytime any of the records are updated (Journey Template, Template Step or Template sub Step records) **Template Last Modified** is updated

At the Journey Level, the field "**Last Synced Date**" is updated when at Journey Template is added to a Journey record.
Finally, **Journey of date** field is true *`if Last Synced date < Last Template Modified.`*
So here I know that my Journey Template (e.g. Marketing BNPP - Template) and the Journey using this particular template are not in sync.

My idea is to use the field Journey out of date as the trigger to update a Journey record.

With all of that in mind, what would be the best way to update all records using a specific template (e.g. **Marketing BNPP - Template**) so all the information & changes at template level are reproduced / mirrored at Journey level

Thanks

Comment: A batch class being called by a trigger on template object that updates all Journies using the template which was updated?

Comment: Thanks, will try that